# How to abstract away values from Xcode storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode

In Android, you can either program the user interface using the visual editor or the xml editor. Values can either be literal, or pointers to another xml config file where they are stored in a central location.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/my_height"/>
```

As a new user to Xcode, I have noticed that there is not really an "xml editor" and everything is more or less done in the visual editor. Unfortunately this means that all values (padding,etc) have to be hard coded. Is there any way to make the values point to an external xml/json config file? `@dimen/my_height`?

[image]

P.S. is there really no alternative to the visual editor in xcode? I feel as if it is just a nightmare waiting to happen. A bunch of defaults that you are unfamiliar with that might burn you, as well as being hard to check for changes in - there is just too much autogenerated cruft.

[image]

Comment: You can create `IBOutlet` variable for any constraint and change it in code as you like?

Comment: You can always do everything in code. That’s pretty much the choices Apple allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Interface Builder to associate the laid out UI elements with your own code by connecting outlets. IBOutlet is a place marker to tell Xcode that this object in the code can be connected to a UI component in Interface Builder which allows the UI constructed in Interface Builder to receive messages from the code.

There are tons of tutorials about it. Just do a quick search please. Check this Apple tutorial to see how you can connect ui to your code. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: This is not what I asked at all. Did you even read my question?

Comment: I read your question. IBOutlets are one way of doing it.  If you want, you can create all your paddings with auto layout visual format such as  `let views = ["myView" : myView]
let formatString = "|-[myView]-|"
let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: formatString, options: .alignAllTop, metrics: nil, views: views)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)` which creates and activates both the leading and trailing constraints for a given view.

Comment: It's a matter of choice.. Also if you spend a little bit time with the storyboard and the IB you will see that there are some cases its better to use the IB instead of doing everything in the code. So you are not limited! Check the Apple resources https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1